# UIImageView XY Coordinates with Layer Movement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coordinates, layer

I move my `UIImageView` with layer around the screen. When at some point I'm trying to retrieve x and y coordinates of a moved imageView using `imageView.frame.origin.x` I receive original coordinates not the new ones after the move. How to get X and Y correctly?

---

Here is my code:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];  
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imgNameArr];    
imageView.animationDuration = 2;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];   
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.duration = speed;
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO; 
CGMutablePathRef pointPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pointPath, NULL, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pointPath, NULL, x, y);
pathAnimation.path = pointPath;
CGPathRelease(pointPath);   
[imageView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pathAnimation%@",objId]];
[imageView release];
```

Comment: Can you include a code snippet?  Are you calling setNeedsLayout or layoutIfNeeded?

Comment: There's too little information. How about posting some code?

Comment: My answer already posted is correct for this code. Set an animation on the UIImageView's centre rather than it's layer's position. Otherwise `frame` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for the `frame` property:

> Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the
>   value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

The `frame` property also becomes undefined if you adjust that view's layer's `transform` or `affineTransform` properties (which are actually what the UIView alters when you set its transform). In Cocoa Touch transforms are applied at the time of compositing by the compositor. At present what you seem to get when a transform is applied is the original frame as though there were no transform, but as the docs say it's undefined so don't rely on that.

If you're just moving the view around with no other transformation, I recommend you use the view's `center` property rather than applying a transform. That will update your frame correctly. Based on empirical evidence, UIKit also seems smart enough that just adjusting the centre doesn't have any performance downside compared to applying a transform.

Comment: I have to use layer because my path is very complex.

Comment: Then have you tried reading back the `layer.position` property? That should be correct after the animation. It may even be worth abandoning the frame property altogether — set up your view initially so that it has the correct size and is at (0, 0) then do the rest through layer.position.

Comment: Yes I tried recently all - layer.frame, layer.bounds and layer.position - everything points to original location

Comment: What do you get if you inspect layer.transform?

Comment: layer.transform.m11, for example, is 1.0; then all others are mostly 0.0 and a few 1.0's